# How to implement Sql helper class in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UserRegister_Insert",
                        new SqlParameter("@firstname",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50),
                        new SqlParameter("@lastname",LastName),
                        new SqlParameter("@email",Email),
                        new SqlParameter("@password",Password),
                        new SqlParameter("@contactno",ContactNo));
```

I have also implemented sql helper class but the members of that class are unable to access.

Comment: how you are assigning connection string!! Post some more details!!

Comment: Through `webconfig` fine. But how you are assigning it to your `conString` variable and is that in the same page or different page??

Comment: Did you check if your ExecuteNonQuery method is declared as Shared? If it's not supposed to be shared, did you Instantiate your SqlHelper class?

Comment: it is in the Sqlhelper class

Comment: No sqlhelper class is not instantiated due to security reasons

Comment: but reference is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error at connection string that it is not defined in current context ?
 
Please take a string variable and initialize it just above your code and try to run it

```
String conString=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;//your connection string name
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UserRegister_Insert",
                        new SqlParameter("@firstname",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50),
                        new SqlParameter("@lastname",LastName),
                        new SqlParameter("@email",Email),
                        new SqlParameter("@password",Password),
                        new SqlParameter("@contactno",ContactNo));
```